# <see cref> XML comment for byte[] without errors

Tags: c#, xml-comments

I'm trying to write a `<see cref>` XML comment for the type `byte[]`.

Unfortunately, the standard syntax:

```
<see cref="T:System.Byte[]">
```

causes an error when executing the **Remove and Sort using VS command**, as described here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785457/remove-unused-usings-falsely-reports-that-project-does-not-build-for-certain-files

The fact is that this is the correct syntax, but it causes the error anyway.

For now, I used the `<c>` tag to just emphasize the type name in the commentary, but this is obviously a workaround.

Anyone knows a syntax that compile and does not cause that nasty VS bug to come out?

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct syntax. The only thing you could potentially do is to disable the option to treat warnings as errors. If you don't want to do that, there is really nothing you can do to work around the error. This has been fixed in Visual Studio 2015 because it's been fixed in the underlying Roslyn implementation of the language services.